# How do I remove all i386 architecture packages from my Debian installation?

Tags: debian, 32-vs-64-bit

I added foreign architecture `i386` to my Debian `amd64` installation.  How do I remove it?  When I try this command: `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`, I am told to first remove all `i386` packages.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I am answering my own question after gathering important information from other blog posts.

1. Show what foreign architectures are installed: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

   - Might show: `i386`
2. Review `i386` packages on your system: `dpkg -l | grep i386`
3. Remove all `i386` packages: `apt-get purge ".*:i386"`

   - Note: The `purge` keyword (instead of `remove`) removes all configuration files associated with the packages you're uninstalling.  (Thanks PCGuyIV!)
4. Now you can remove the `i386` architecture: `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: Rejected edit from https://superuser.com/users/944626/benjamin-buch, but still a good comment: "You might need apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential ".*:i386" to remove libc and other essential packages. Be very careful with --allow-remove-essential because it will kill your system if you accidentally remove the 64 bit version instead of the 32 bit one!"

Comment: complete command is like this : ```apt remove `dpkg --get-selections |grep :i386 |awk '{print $1}'` --allow-remove-essential -f``` and after that `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: Is this "safe"? I'm trying to understand why i386 packages are installed ... if running in float32 mode for some frameworks I wonder if hte i386 are ever used. It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 35):

I would use "purge" instead of "remove".

```
~# apt-get purge ".*:i386"
~# dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

The "purge" keyword removes all configuration files associated with the packages you're uninstalling.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain the difference and ramifications?

Answer (score 12):

```
$ sudo apt remove `dpkg --get-selections |grep :i386 |awk '{print $1}'`
$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Comment: ONLY USE THIS ANSWER OR YOU WILL LOOSE LOTS OF PACKAGES!

Comment: I would suggest that you change the grep to grep ':i386 '.  this is because some other packages have i386 in the description text. @WGRM